# Calculate difference between two dynamic dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the number of days between two dynamic dates.

I have a product where credits are renewed the day 19th, and I want to show the user how many days remain to renew them.

I have tried this code with no success: if today it's November 22nd, the result that this code returns is a negative number, when it should return "27" as there are 27 days between today and December 19th.

```
var today = new Date();
var todayMonth = today.getMonth()+1;
if(todayMonth<10) todayMonth = 0+todayMonth;
var datetwo = new Date(today.getFullYear()+"-"+todayMonth+"-19T00:00:00.000Z");
var dayDif = (datetwo - today)  / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
dayDif = Math.ceil(dayDif);

var daysLeftRenew = dayDif;
```

I also tried with Moment.js, but I cannot find how to work with dynamic dates like this.

Comment: So, you are checking the difference between dates within the same month?

Comment: Not exactly: if today it's November 22nd, the following 19th will be December 19th.

Comment: @JuanjoRubio In that case check my answer.

Comment: @JuanjoRubio You have a small bug in your code. That has nothing to do with your question. You don't replace the value on12 in `todayMonth`. You have to replace to value 0, because the month values have only a range from 0 to 11.

Comment: @JuanjoRubio The reason for your trouble is simple and cirous: even though the new date string is right, the method `datetwo.getMonth()`returns a wrong value. Whatever the reason is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates manipulation may be tricky, you can consider using dedicated library for such computations like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It will also make code code much more clean:

```js
var targetDate = moment().date(19);
if (targetDate.isBefore(moment())) {
  targetDate.add(1, 'month');
}
console.log(targetDate.endOf('day').fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works like a charm! But, is there any way to format the result that this code returns? I don't find it on the Moment.js documentation. If the days between today and 19th is bigger than 25, it returns "in a month".

Comment: `fromNow` and related methods are specially designed to respond with relative dates with dynamic scale. If you need different output - you can use [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) method to get and then use it to create [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) object and format it to the taste

Answer (score 0):

> if today it's November 22nd, the result that this code returns is a
>   negative number, when it should return "27" as there are 27 days
>   between today and December 19th.

You need to change this line

```
var todayMonth = today.getMonth()+1;
```

to

```
var todayMonth = today.getMonth()+2;//2 instead of 1 as getMonth will give value starting from 0 to 11.
```

since you are setting the **month parameter within the string format** and it will take the month parameter as is.

**Demo**

```js
var today = new Date();
var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 2;
if (todayMonth < 10) todayMonth = 0 + todayMonth;
var datetwo = new Date(today.getFullYear() + "-" + todayMonth + "-19T00:00:00.000Z");
var dayDif = (datetwo - today) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
dayDif = Math.ceil(dayDif);
var daysLeftRenew = dayDif;
console.log(daysLeftRenew);
```